# Shopify liquid loop current_tags

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Shopify creates a URL to each collection filter. This URL `https://example.com/collections/default/type_tag+size_tag+width_tag` would filter products on a collection called `default` to show products that are tagged with type_tag, size_tag, width_tag.

This also creates a canonical link with the same `href` as the above URL. In this example, the canonical href would be `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/collections/default/type_tag+size_tag+width_tag">`

We want to optimize for SEO. For URLs with the same filters but inverse (and therefore yield the same page and filtered content) we would like to have the same canonical href.

For example: These URLs would filter the same products on collections `default` and show canonicals with matching href value.

`https://example.com/collections/default/type_tag+size_tag+width_tag`
`https://example.com/collections/default/size_tag+width_tag+type_tag`
`https://example.com/collections/default/type_tag+width_tag+size_tag`
`https://example.com/collections/default/width_tag+type_tag+size_tag`

Regardless of the URLs above, we would like the canonical href to be fixed as the one we set. So as an example, we want the above URLs to have `https://example.com/collections/default/type_tag+size_tag+width_tag` as the canonical.

As you can tell, our tags are grouped into type_, size_ and width_.

I have tried several methods to loop over the `{% current_tags %}` object to check if any of the tags in {% current_tags %} contains type_, size_ and width_. Below is the idea that I have but clearly it doesn't work so it's trash. Fresh ideas please and thank you!!!

```
{% if template contains 'collection' and current_tags %}
{% for tag in current_tags %}  
   {% if current_tags contains 'type_' %}
       {% assign type_tag_url = tag  %}
   {% elsif current_tags contains 'size_' %}
       {% assign size_tag_url = tag  %}
   {% elsif current_tags contains 'width_' %}
       {% assign width_tag_url = tag  %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}/{{type_tag_url}}+{{size_tag_url}}+{{width_tag_url}}" />

{% else %}
        <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current_tags` is an array. When you use `contains` operator to find items in the array the comparison works based on an exact match. So you cannot use it to check whether it contains tags that contain a part of the string, like `type_`. Check the tags itself instead e.g.:

```
{% if template contains 'collection' and current_tags %}
  {% for tag in current_tags %}  
    {% if tag contains 'type_' %}
       {% assign type_tag_url = tag  %}
    {% elsif tag contains 'size_' %}
       {% assign size_tag_url = tag  %}
    {% elsif tag contains 'width_' %}
       {% assign width_tag_url = tag  %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}/{{type_tag_url}}+{{size_tag_url}}+{{width_tag_url}}" />

{% else %}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Vladimir. I tried that before and tried yours just now but it doesn't work. The canonical returned is `<link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}/++ />`. The assigned variables {`{type_tag_url}}, {{size_tag_url}}, {{width_tag_url}}` return empty or undefined.

Comment: I just tested it and it's working as expected. I opened the `/collections/test/size_m+type_t-shirt+width_45cm` path and here's how canonical URL looks like: `/collections/test/type_t-shirt+size_m+width_45cm`

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why mine returns `/collections/default/++`. In theme.liquid inside `<head>` tag, I have `{% render 'canonicals' %}`. My canonicals code is in a snippet file called `canonicals.liquid`. Anyway I'm going to accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I've just tested it using snippet and `render` operator and got the working result. Really weird. Is there a public URL available for testing?

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7Lcv2qfb/ for link to preview our test site. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to output the `{{ current_tags }}` variable and every tag in the loop itself? Also, output the values of the link variables on every iteration. That way you will be able to see what's happening.